# How to enable the Hibernate HiLo entity identifier optimizer strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, identifier, hilo

I'm initializing Hibernate without any XML by something like

```
org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
    new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration().
    .setProperty(...)
    .setProperty(...)
    ...
    .buildSessionFactory();
```

My classes use an ID like

```
@Id @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT) @GeneratedValue private Integer id;
```

The generator used is `SequenceStyleGenerator`, which seems to be the replacement for the deprecated `SequenceGenerator` and `SequenceHiLoGenerator` and whatever. It uses

```
public static final int DEFAULT_INCREMENT_SIZE = 1;
```

and seems to allow configuration via

```
public static final String INCREMENT_PARAM = "increment_size";
```

but that's all I could find out. I guess I have to set some property "xxx.yyy.increment_size" or pass it in another way to Hibernate, but I can't see how.

---

I'm aware of `@SequenceGenerator`, but it seems to be completely ignored

Comment: The default values as always useless, why not did you use a physical sequence and you can also use auto increment if you create a trigger on insert before each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for how to set `increment_size` property for your `SequenceSytleGenerator`.

Sample snippet below setting `increment_size` using `@GenericGenerator` annotation with `hilo` optimizer and `SEQUENCE` strategy.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hilo_generator")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "hilo_generator",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
                // Or leave it out to get "hibernate_sequence".
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "hilo_sequence"),
                // Or leave it out as this is the default.
                @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "5"),
                @Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "hilo")
        })
```

There's no way you can globally set the `DEFAULT_INCREMENT_SIZE` with a Hibernate configuration property. You need to use the `@Id` configuration properties instead.

Answer (score 1):

### @Generated vs @GeneratedValue

You don't need to use `@Generated` along with `@GeneratedValue`. The `@Generated` annotation is for the non-id entity attributes that are generated by the database during INSERT or UPDATE. For more details about the `@Generated` annotation.

On the other hand, the `@GeneratedValue` is only for the entity identifier attributes, and it's what you need to use when the entity identifier is generated automatically upon persisting an entity.

### Sequence generator

The sequence generator requires an extra database roundtrip to call the sequence object when you persist the entity. For this reason, Hibernate offers sequence-based optimizers to reduce the number of roundtrips needed to fetch entity identifier values.

Now, if you want to use `hilo`, the identifier mapping will look as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
    generator = "post_sequence"
)
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "post_sequence",
    strategy = "sequence",
    parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "sequence_name",  value = "post_sequence"),
        @Parameter(name = "initial_value",  value = "1"),
        @Parameter(name = "increment_size",  value = "3"),
        @Parameter(name = "optimizer", value = "hilo")
    }
)
private Long id;
```

Apart from having to use the Hibernate-specific `@GenericGenerator`, the problem with `hilo` is that the generated identifiers don't include the database sequence value, so an 3rd-party client using the database will not know how to generate the next identifier value unless they know the `hilo` algorithm and the `allocationSize`.

For this reason, it's better to use `pooled` or `pooled-lo`.

### Pooled optimizer

The `pooled` optimizer is very easy to set up. All you need to do is set the `allocationSize` of the JPA `@SequenceGenerator` annotation, and Hibernate is going to switch to using the `pooled` optimizer:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
    generator = "post_sequence"
)
@SequenceGenerator(
    name = "post_sequence",
    sequenceName = "post_sequence",
    allocationSize = 3
)
private Long id;
```

[image: Hibernate pooled optimizere]

### Pooled-lo optimizer

To use the pooled-lo optimizer, just add the following configuration property:

```
<property name="hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred" value="pooled-lo" />
```

Now, the entity identifier mapping is identical to the one I showed you before for the `pooled` optimizer.

To understand how the pooled-lo works, check out this diagram:

[image: Hibernate pooled-lo optimizer]

> If you have been using the legacy `hilo` optimizer, you might want to switch to using `pooled` or `pooled-lo`, as `hilo` is not interoperable with other clients that might not be aware of the [`hilo`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/) identifier allocation strategy.

Comment: can I use hilo optimizer from multiple instances of my server (obviously using the same configuration of generator) ?

Comment: Yes, you can. It's the same as using multiple threads on the same server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072871/hibernate-jpa-hilo-strategy-not-generating-the-values-according-to-next-value

Comment: Can you look at this question I posted related to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207261/discussion-between-user2599052-and-vlad-mihalcea).